# Can I switch to a different PTS session opened using SSH

Tags: command-line, ssh, login, tty

I'm using ssh to connect to a Ubuntu Server VM running on my desktop from both the desktop and my laptop like this:

```
krzysztof@Alan: ~$ ▶ w
 13:53:46 up 1 day, 18:03,  7 users,  load average: 0.32, 0.27, 0.22
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
krzyszto pts/0    10.0.0.14        13:53    1.00s  0.08s  0.00s w
krzyszto pts/1    10.0.0.8         Wed22   13:57m  4.27s  3.82s -zsh
krzyszto pts/5    10.0.0.8         Thu21   13:36m  0.58s  0.58s -zsh
krzyszto pts/6    10.0.0.14        10:29    7.00s  0.53s  0.05s python /opt/impala/shell/impala_shell.py --ssl --ca_cert=/xyz
```

10.0.0.14 is laptop, 10.0.0.8 is desktop.

However, let's assume that I left an application (e.g. spark or impala shell) running in the SSH session on pts/6 on my laptop and went back to my desktop. Is it possible somehow to switch to that application when logging in using ssh or when I'm already logged in?

I'm asking this question because I couldn't infer this from other posts that I've seen. The thing is that I might have left on the other computer an application running something and I want to continue working with that app. Can I take it over somehow without killing it? All session run under one user account but from different SSH connections.

I probably still don't understand the difference between TTY and PTS, but **chvt** doesn't seem to work with ssh and/or pts. Additionally, I've seen suggestions to use **tmux** or **screen**, but I'd be more comfortable with something simpler.